# Powershell invoke tool with argument containing a wildcard

Tags: powershell, escaping, wildcard

I'm writing a tool that receives an argument that is a file pattern as follows:

```
mytool arg1 *
```

Here is the problem: The character `*` is being resolved to the contents of the current directory, almost like the `ls` command.
If I escape the wildcard using grave (`) it is also received by the command.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: function -> named parameters? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)<sup>[1]</sup> to prevent the globbing (pathname extension) that PowerShell performs *on Unix*-like platforms (only) when calling *external programs*:

```
mytool arg1 '*'
```

I have no explanation for why character-individual escaping (`` `* ``) *doesn't* work (as of PowerShell 7.2.6) - arguably, it should; the problem has been reported in [GitHub issue #18038](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18038).

---

On *Windows*, PowerShell performs *no* globbing, and `*`, `'*'`, and `` `* `` are all passed as verbatim `*` to an external program.

As you state, given that you're on Windows, it must be the Python-based tool you're calling that performs globbing.

---

<sup>[1] An [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) string works too, but there's no need for one unless you truly need expansion (string interpolation).</sup>

Comment: Since you said it should work, I've done a simple tool to just show the arguments. It all works (wildcard, escaped wildcard and verbatim string). It seems to be related to python environment somehow. The tool in question is an installed python package. There is a lot in the way. I'll investigate further to identify the guilty. Thank you!

Comment: I'm on Windows, so it's definitely on python. Might not be python environment, but some library (click.palletsprojects.com to be more specific). I haven't found where it happens yet.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @PauloAlves - I've updated the answer accordingly.